# How to change UI from a WearableListenerService?

Tags: android, multithreading

I know this question has been answered multiple times but being new to Android I still can't understand the answers given. In this question for instance: [How to use an Android Handler to update a TextView in the UI Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685752/how-to-use-an-android-handler-to-update-a-textview-in-the-ui-thread) and then there is this question where the answer is very unclear too: [Using Data API changes to update watch face UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058284/using-data-api-changes-to-update-watch-face-ui).

I have a MainActivity.class that has a RadioButton that shows whether the phone is currently acquiring data from Android Wear's sensors. The Service that starts acquiring data is named MyService and extends WearableListenerService. All I need to do is set the RadioButton to true or false depending on the value of the boolean that I'm controlling in MyService.class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it isn't always good to answer your own question but I'll answer just so that someone in the future might benefit.
The answer that worked for me is here:
[Android update activity UI from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695537/android-update-activity-ui-from-service)

This guy posted two solutions in his answer, the second one worked for me.